# Google spreadsheets : display all decimals, but no trailing zeroes

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I want a number format that achieves both these results in one go :

```
1.2
3.456789
```

If change the number of decimals I can either get :

```
1.2
3.5
```

OR :

```
1.200000
3.456789
```

Neither of which I do want.